# Conditional join that changes number of join conditions

Tags: sql

I am trying to join data based on the following scenario.

Let's say there are two businesses. Business 1 has one field for customer data, business 2 has two fields. I need to join to multiple other tables using these customer fields.

I would like to create a join that joins on just field 1 for business 1, but field 1 AND field 2 for business 2. In other words, there is a more granular identifier available for business 2, but it is still valid to join on just field 1 for business 1 as well. It also needs to function like an inner join, in that we are only preserving the relevant data that match these conditions.

The code would look something like this for business 1:

```
FROM customer_data a
INNER JOIN marketing_data b
ON a.member_number = b.member_number
WHERE business_number = 1
```

And something like this for business 2:

```
FROM customer_data a
INNER JOIN marketing_data b
ON a.member_number = b.member_number
AND a.sub_member_number = b.sub_member_number
WHERE business_number = 2
```

I am hoping to extract both sets of data in one join statement. Also, just in case it helps, I am using the Snowflake platform to write my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work for both the cases.

```
FROM customer_data a
INNER JOIN marketing_data b ON a.member_number = b.member_number
WHERE (
        a.sub_member_number = b.sub_member_number
        AND business_number = 2
        )
    OR business_number = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the conditions in the `ON` clause like this:

```
FROM customer_data cd INNER JOIN
     marketing_data md
     ON cd.member_number = md.member_number AND
        ( cd.business_number <> 2 OR
          cd.sub_member_number = md.sub_member_number
        )
```

Note:  this generalizes beyond just businesses 1 and 2, with the special condition only applying to 2.   The first condition can be `= 1` if you want to be more specific.

Also note that this introduces *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.  This makes queries much easier to understand.